# why terraform import does not generate configuration?

Tags: terraform

They specifically said it doesn't generate the config, but I am curious as to why?

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/state-import?utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS

> You can use the import command to migrate existing resources into your Terraform state file. The import command does not currently generate the configuration for the imported resource, so you must write the corresponding configuration block to map the imported resource to it.

Comment: Not every aspect of the configurations are discoverable via API. You'd get in a broken state and find out only once you had to recreate the resource.

Comment: `terraformer` by Google most famously does this, but traditionally it is best as a "discovery and scaffolding" tool, and its output should not really be used "as is".

Comment: I would say it's because that is out-of-scope for what HashiCorp wants to do with Terraform. It would actually add a ton of extra complication to Terraform providers.

Answer (score 0):

The translation from configuration to desired state and then from desired state to actual state are both "lossy" in the sense that Terraform discards information during the process.

For example, if you want to create three EC2 instances, there are multiple different ways to describe that, including:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example1" {
  # ..
}

resource "aws_instance" "example2" {
  # ..
}

resource "aws_instance" "example3" {
  # ..
}
```

```
locals {
  ec2_instances = tomap({
    "a" = { /* ... */ }
    "b" = { /* ... */ }
    "c" = { /* ... */ }
  })
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  for_each = local.ec2_instances
}
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 3
}
```

As far as the remote EC2 API is concerned, these all describe an equivalent result: three separate EC2 instances. There is no information in the remote API about how you declared them.

When you use `terraform import` you are effectively asking Terraform to work "backwards": instead of starting with configuration and evaluating it to produce a desired state and then sending that desired state to a provider, importing starts with the remote object fetched by the provider. Terraform doesn't have any information about which of the many different possible ways you want to write this configuration, so it just focuses on updating the state (since the relationship between state and the remote system is much less "lossy") and leaves you to write a desired state which matches that state.

The decision of how to declare multiple objects of the same type is just one example. There are various different ways to write the same thing in Terraform configuration in many different situations, such as loading information from an external file, using a data source to dynamically declare a set of objects based on some other set of objects, and so on. Terraform has no way to understand just from the remote API contents which of those is appropriate for your situation, and so Terraform requires that you write a configuration which matches as close as possible the original design intent of the system you're now importing into Terraform.